# Azure sentinel alternative in azure

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-sentinel

Is there any alternative of azure sentinel because it is very costly.
Any suggestions regarding this would be very helpful for me

Comment: Your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow for two reasons as a) your question is purely asking for recommendations, b) it's not about programming. [sf] is a site for asking professional server and networking questions, but this question would almost certainly be off-topic there, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are many competitive products available, however, you won't find one that is less costly. That said, there are steps and best practices that can be applied during Azure Sentinel deployment that can greatly minimize costs.

Reach out to your Microsoft rep for help with this.